# Filtering error reports in rails production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Applications have notifications issued via e-mail as set-up in `environments/production.rb' :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[error] -  ",
    :sender_address => %{"notifier" no-reply@domain.ws},
    :exception_recipients => %w{notifications@domain4.us}
  }
```

All the bad actors probing an appication are generating a 404 error (*including google with `'A=0`string*), which in turn generates notifications which are by and large noise pollution. (there is no point in blocking ips, we've just observed a chain of probes with the same string coming from 12 different ip addresses...)

A serendipitous side effect of having i18n enabled and the locale added to the URL means that all these errors are of the same type `some_darned_string  "is not a valid locale"`.  Processing a 404 error is acceptable in terms of performance hit relative to leaving the bad actor in the dark.

The question however is, how can we conditionally filter ExceptionNotification::Rack to not send the mail when its contents has the string `is not a valid locale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom exceptions to the ignore list

See [Ignore Exceptions](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#ignore-exceptions)

There are also some useful options like `ignore_crawlers` or `ignore_if` that'll allow you to filter exceptions based on their contents

Comment: this is not part of rails but the `exception_notification` gem - which is where my memory had failed me [blush].  For this particular instance, the exception can be set as `I18n::InvalidLocale`.